# How can I increase memory and enable remote debugging when using Jetty with Ant?

Tags: java, ant, jetty

I am trying to use Jetty with ant and for the most part I've followed the instructions outlined [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Ant+Jetty+Plugin). The webapp starts up ok but I still to make a few more adjustments:

- Increase JVM memory (set the -Xms, -Xmx, and -XX:MaxPermSize)
- Enable remote debugging

My ant task is defined as such:

```
  <target name="jetty" depends="make-webapp">
    <taskdef resource="tasks.properties" loaderref="jetty.loader">
      <classpath>
        <fileset dir="jetty-lib/">
          <include name="eclipse-jdt-core-3.1.1.jar" />
          <include name="jetty-6.1.26.jar" />
          <include name="jetty-ant-6.1.26.jar" />
          <include name="jetty-naming-6.1.26.jar" />
          <include name="jetty-plus-6.1.26.jar" />
          <include name="jetty-util-6.1.26.jar" />
          <include name="jsp-2.1-jetty-6.1.16.jar" />
          <include name="jsp-api-2.1-glassfish-9.1.1.B51.25.p1.jar" />
          <include name="jsp-2.1-glassfish-9.1.1.B51.25.p1.jar" />
          <include name="servlet-api-2.5-6.1.5.jar" />
        </fileset>
      </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <mkdir dir="target/work" />
    <jetty tempDirectory="target/work">
      <webApp
        name="myapp"
        warfile="target/myapp"
        contextpath="/myapp" />
    </jetty>
  </target>
```

target/myapp has everything it needs including the WEB-INF/lib and WEB-INF/classes folders.

So how can I increase memory and enable remote debugging with this set up?

Comment: isn't it enough to set the environment variable "ANT_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"? or does jetty ant task run in an own JVM?

Comment: That seems to work for increasing the memory. Might it also work for debugging? I ran `set ANT_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx512m -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n -Xdebug"` but wasn't able to successfully debug in Eclipse.

Comment: try `suspend=yes`, remote connect your debugger (e.g. eclipse->debug->remote localhost:8000) then your tests should not start until eclipse connected and you started the process again by hitting the resume button

Comment: Nope. Still doesn't seem to work with suspend=y. That technique feels awkward anyway, since I'm actually debugging ant and would have to wait for eclipse to run any build targets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might answer your question: http://ptrthomas.wordpress.com/2006/10/10/how-to-start-and-stop-jetty-from-ant/

Use jvmarg to put the required memory and remote debugging settings.